# PiCamera Multiple Video File Recording H264

Tags: python, pi-2, camera, raspicam

I want to know if it's possible to record four H264 video files with PiCamera with a specific frame ?

For example, I am recording 10 seconds of video at 4 fps. So normally, I will get a video file of 10 seconds with 40 frames. But now what I am trying to do, it's taking the:

- 1st frame and put it into CAM1.h264
- take the 2nd frame and put it into CAM2.h264
- take the 3rd frame and put in into CAM3.H264
- take the 4th frame and put it into CAM4.h264
- take the 5th frame and put in into CAM1.h264
- take the 6th frame and put in into CAM2.h264
- take the 7rd frame and put in into CAM3.H264
- take the 8th frame and put it into CAM4.h264
- take the 9th frame and put in into CAM1.h264
- take the 10th frame and put in into CAM2.h264
- take the 11rd frame and put in into CAM3.H264
- take the 12th frame and put it into CAM4.h264
  etc.

How may I accomplish this ? With a stream ?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this in real time, but I've got a feeling you might be able to do some frame splicing after recording using ffmpeg. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply ! Do you have an example of code that I can use for the Frame Splicing after recording using FFMPEG ? It could be a good idea !

Comment: I have a camera that takes pics at slow intervals and ffmpeg combines then into a video. You could dump your video to pics and combine them into four videos with four commands.

Comment: Hi PaulF8080, thanks for your fast reply ! Do you have any tutorial or links on how I can acheived this properly ?

Comment: I do not understand your question, you say you want a new file per frame, but why would you want that in h264 format. When it would be much simpler to write a small script to take 4 photos per second for 10 seconds and a script may give you more control over the file naming.

Comment: There are lots of tutorials if you Google ffmpeg timelapse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Lots of fun head scratching trying to remember how expressions work in ffmpeg!

This is still fairly non-optimal - you need to run a separate ffmpeg pass for the frame 1,5,9... video, the frame 2,6,10... video, the frame 3,7,11 video, etc. This could probably be automated with a small script. I'm also unsure of how long all this will take - the time required will depend on your source footage.

Where `in.mp4` is your input video file:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,4))" -vsync vfr out1.mp4
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "select=not(mod(n+1\,4))" -vsync vfr out2.mp4
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "select=not(mod(n+2\,4))" -vsync vfr out3.mp4
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "select=not(mod(n+3\,4))" -vsync vfr out4.mp4
```

This uses the [select filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) to define which frames to output. The [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation) describes my expression components as:

> - **mod(x, y)**: Compute the remainder of division of x by y.
> - **not(expr):**    Return 1.0 if expr is zero, 0.0 otherwise.